# Convert IntPtr to char** in C#

Tags: c#, memory-management, types, type-conversion, dllimport

I'd like to interpret the output of the following unmanaged function:

```
afc_error_t afc_get_device_info (afc_client_t client, char ***device_information)
```

I import the dll with the code:

```
[DllImport("libimobiledevice.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern short afc_get_device_info(IntPtr client, out IntPtr info);
```

As long as I only needed to convert response to string `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` was okay. However I have no idea how to convert that IntPtr back to char array.

Comment: You are importing two different functions, with different names and different number of parametrs... And the fisrt one was `char***`... (I'll have to say, a `***` is something rare even in the C world :-) )

Comment: @xanatos Yeah, sry, I corrected the name. char*** is because it gives back a char** (for example if it gave back a string it would be char** outputString).

Comment: @geislza and the second example is an example of an unrelated method of the same library that you are using, right?

Comment: @xanatos If you mean the Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi, then yes, that's used at another function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
IntPtr di;

int result = afc_read_directory(client, @"C:\", out di);

if (di == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    throw new Exception();
}

IntPtr di2 = di;

while (true)
{
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(di2);

    if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        break;
    }

    string str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);

    if (str == string.Empty)
    {
        break;
    }

    di2 = di2 + IntPtr.Size;
}
```

Try if it works, then I'll explain how...

**important** you are leaking memory here...

I've found this example in C:

```
char **dirs = NULL;
afc_read_directory(afc, "/eafaedf", &dirs);
if (!dirs)
    afc_read_directory(afc, "/", &dirs);
printf("Directory time.\n");
for (i = 0; dirs[i]; i++) {
    printf("/%s\n", dirs[i]);
    free(dirs[i]);
}
if (dirs)
    free(dirs);
```

**you** are responsible for freeing the memory (see the `free` inside the cycle and the final **free**?). In this case (and for other methods that return arrays of C-strings you can use `afc_dictionary_free`. Note that other methods like `afc_receive_data` that return a single block of memory you can't use it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. There is an afc_dictionary_free function in the same library. I think that does the freeing properly.

Comment: @Geiszla Yep... It does. Just looked at its source code.

Comment: @Geiszla If you want to use that method, note that you have to change the code. I've already updated the answer. I was modifying the original `IntPtr di`, but you need to keep a copy to use it with the `afc_dictionary_free`